# On mobile, how far apart should related checkboxes be from each other?

Tags: checkboxes, grid

I have a grid layout that looks like this:

__ Item1 __ Item2
__ Item3 __ Item4

The __ are checkboxes. How far from the other checkboxes should they be?

Answer (score 3):

The simple answer is that, whatever screen they're on, it should be easy to distinguish whether a checkbox relates to the label on the left or the right of it.

Working in a small space makes it tempting to push things closer together but this can cause problems for people using the UI at speed, while distracted, or experiencing some other cognitive drain.

With checkboxes, you can end up in a situation where a distracted user can not tell which option they are checking:

[image]

[Gestalt psychology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principles_of_grouping) breaks down because it's unclear what the grouping actually is. We know that, in reality, there would normally be another checkbox to offer some context but, when the user is distracted, they won't necessarily look for that context.

You need to make the grouping between the checkbox and label as obvious as possible to ensure your users understand what is going on:

[image]

There are no rules for how many pixels this spacing needs to be. You should experiment to see what works best for you - just remember that you need to be sure that the users shouldn't be able to guess that a checkbox belongs to the wrong label.